# Microsoft HPC Scheduler not getting connected

Tags: .net, hpc

I have this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Hpc.Scheduler.Scheduler scheduler = 
                new Microsoft.Hpc.Scheduler.Scheduler();

            Console.Write(scheduler.ClusterParameters + "\n" +
                scheduler.EnvironmentVariables + "\n");

        }
```

This is generating an exception. After the scheduler object is created, the properties ClusterParameters and EnvironmentVariables are holding exceptions.

The exception is, "Microsoft.Hpc.Scheduler.SchedulerException - The operation failed because you are not connected to the scheduler"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.scheduler.scheduler%28VS.85%29.aspx) suggest you do not use the `Scheduler` class directly.  Do this instead:

```
IScheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
```

Once you've done this you would have to [Connect to be able to use the properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.scheduler.ischeduler%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  That's why you get that exception.

> After creating an instance of this
>   interface, call the IScheduler.Connect
>   method to connect to a cluster. You
>   can then create and schedule jobs, run
>   commands, and retrieve information
>   about nodes in the cluster.